# LRU cache using multiple keys?

Tags: python

So, I have a code like following:

```
cache = {}

def fetch_data(keys):
     vals_in_cache, keys_to_fetch = check_cache(keys)
     new_vals = fetch_data_from_api(keys_to_fetch)
     update_cache(new_vals) # add these k,v in cache
     # new_vals = {key:val ..} dict
     all_vals = vals_in_cache.update(keys_to_fetch)
     return all_vals

def check_cache(keys):
     vals_in_cache, to_fetch = {}, []
     for key in keys:
          if key in cache:
              vals_in_cache[key] = cache[key]
          else:
             to_fetch.append(key)
    return vals_in_cache, to_fetch
```

Clearly, this is a dumb cache.
I want to use LRU cache or something more proper..
But, my issue is that fetch_data_from_api call accepts list as parameter and since the call happens over network.. its better to get all values in one go... rather than multiple calls to api...
Also, this method is slow as each time... I have to iterate thru the keys..to tease apart what is in cache and what to fetch

What I want is.. a fast way to check multiple keys and fetch their values in cache.. and then things which are not available in cache to be separated out so that I can make a call to fetch the data?
And then also update the cache...

Comment: Are you aware of the functools.lru_cache() decorator from the standard library?

Comment: @BramAppel, that was the first thing I thought of but he has mutable objects as inputs, which will make the use of `lru_cache()` difficult without modifications of the data structure.

Comment: Exactly what version of Python are you using? Does the order of the keys presented to the API in `keys_to_fetch` matter? If it doesn't then it may be feasible…

Comment: @BramAppel yeah.. but how do i send in the list.. I am aware of it being used as atomic values but.. what if we have collections as an input?